# What do I have to do to get Fandjango to work?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[Fandjango](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango) (a Facebook Graph API wrapper for Django) looks great, so I pip install it and I'm off and running or so I think. I try and replicate the basic example given in the [readme](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango/blob/master/README.rst). Well, I get an error there saying that I don't have some settings in my settings.py that aren't mentioned in any of the [pydjango documentation](http://fandjango.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) that I can find, so I do a little digging and find out about [fandjango-example](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango-example).

This seems to be reasonably up to date, so I take the advice dispensed at that page and add some settings to my settings.py:

```
FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID = 181259711925270
FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SECRET_KEY = '214e4cb484c28c35f18a70a3d735999b'
FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_NAMESPACE = 'myapp'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'fandjango.middleware.FacebookMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
]
```

Unfortunately, that's giving me a new error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware facebook.djangofb: "No module named facebook.djangofb"
```

Some more googling, and I see people asking whether pyfacebook is installed. I look into my "pip freeze" and don't find it, so I go and get it from github:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook.git
```

But now I suspect that I'm referencing the wrong facebook object because I'm getting:

```
'Facebook' object has no attribute 'user'
```

So, where did I go wrong?

I'm running Python 2.6 on OS X with

```
Django==1.3.1
South==0.7.3
certifi==0.0.6
distribute==0.6.19
facepy==0.6.4
fandjango==4.0.2
nose==1.1.2
pyfacebook==1.0a2  # will probably kill this
requests==0.8.9
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

(and I also tested it on an AWS Ubuntu micro-instance, same results)

Comment: googling for 'facebook.djangofb' it looks like the sciyoshi/pyfacebook is the right dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fandjango is not related to and does not depend upon pyfacebook. In fact, these libraries are incompatible in that they both add a `facebook` property to the request object. You'll need to remove pyfacebook from your middleware classes if you want to use Fandjango.

Please refer to the the [documentation](http://fandjango.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installation) for installation and configuration instructions.

Comment: Ah, that's the documentation I needed. I missed it the first (and second through fifth) times I visited the site, not realizing that sentence was a link. You may wish to consider add the "installation and configuration" section to the main [table of contents](http://fandjango.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#)